# How can I disable app folders in the GNOME menu permanently?

Tags: fedora, gnome3, dconf

I want to disable 'app folders' in the GNOME menu, because I want to have all applications sorted alphabetically. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children []` lets the folders disappear, but after a reboot the app folders were set back to default. How can I make the settings persistent ? What do I have to do ? Or is this just a bug in fedora 24 or in GNOME 3.20 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be [''] instead of [] - Thanks and reference to the user **zdenek** from the ask fedora platform who helped me to figure it out and find the solution : [How to make app folders settings permanent?](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/94378/how-to-make-customized-gnome-app-folders-settings-persistent/)
The command is : `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children ['']`